# 32-bit malloc() return NULL when opening many threads?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, memory, malloc

I have a sample C++ program as below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void * pointerArr[20000];
    int i = 0, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
        
        void * pointer = malloc(131125);
        if (pointer == NULL) {
            printf("i = %d, out of memory!\n", i);
            getchar();
            break;
        } 
        
        pointerArr[i] = pointer;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        free(pointerArr[j]);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it with Visual Studio 32-bit Debug, it will run with following result:

[image]

The program can use nearly 2Gb of memory before out of memory.
This is normal behavior.

However, when I adding the code to start Thread inside the `for` loop as below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD WINAPI thread_func(VOID* pInArgs)
{
    Sleep(100000);
    return 0;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void * pointerArr[20000];

    int i = 0, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {

        CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread_func, NULL, 0, NULL);
        
        void * pointer = malloc(131125);
        if (pointer == NULL) {
            printf("i = %d, out of memory!\n", i);
            getchar();
            break;
        }

        pointerArr[i] = pointer;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        free(pointerArr[j]);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The result is as below:

[image]

The memory is still just around 200Mb but function `malloc` will return `NULL`.

**Could anyone help explain why the program cannot use the memory up to 2Gb before out of memory?**

Is it mean creating many threads like above will cause memory leak?

In my real application, this error occur when I create about 800 threads, the RAM memory at the time "out of memory" is around 300Mb.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but for CreateThread documentation says "The number of threads a process can create is limited by the available virtual memory. By default, every thread has one megabyte of stack space. "

Comment: I'd like to know is there any tool to measure and show that the threads created above causing out of memory

Comment: Are you sure you understand the figure displayed by Task Manager?

Comment: @IInspectable, not sure. But I think there is some hidden memory/virtual memory that is allocated by `CreateThread` will not shown in Task Manager, is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in a comment by @macroland, the main thing happening here is that each thread is consuming 1 MiB for its stack (see MSDN [CreateThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) and [Thread Stack Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-stack-size)).  You say `malloc` returns `NULL` once the total you have directly allocated reaches 200 MB.  Since you are allocating 131125 bytes at a time, that is 200 MB / 131125 B = 1525 threads.  Their cumulative stack space will be around 1.5 GB.  Adding the 200 MB of `malloc` memory is 1.7 GB, and miscellaneous overhead likely accounts for the rest.

So, why does Task Manager not show this?  Because the full 1 MiB of thread stack space is not actually *allocated* (also called *committed*), rather it is *reserved*.  See [VirtualAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc) and the `MEM_RESERVE` flag.  The address space has been reserved for expansion up to 1 MiB, but initially only 64 KiB are allocated, and Task Manager only counts the latter.  But reserved memory will not be unilaterally repurposed by `malloc` until the reservation is lifted, so once it runs out of available address space, it has to return `NULL`.

What tool can show this?  I don't know of anything off the shelf (even [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) does not seem show a count of reserved memory).  What I have done in the past is write my own little routine that uses [VirtualQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualquery) to enumerate the entire address space, including reserved ranges.  I recommend you do the same; it's not much code to write, and very handy when coding for 32-bit Windows because the 2 GiB address space gets cramped very easily (DLLs are an obvious reason, but the default `malloc` also will leave unexpected reservations behind in response to certain allocation patterns even if you `free` everything).

In any case, if you want to create thousands of threads in a 32-bit Windows process, be sure to pass a non-zero value as the `dwStackSize` parameter to `CreateThread`, and also pass `STACK_SIZE_PARAM_IS_A_RESERVATION` as `dwCreationFlags`.  The minimum is 64 KiB, which will be plenty if you avoid recursive algorithms in the threads.

---

Addendum: In a comment, @iinspectable cautions against using thousands of threads, citing Raymond Chen's 2005 blog post [Does Windows have a limit of 2000 threads per process?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050729-14/?p=34773).  I agree that doing so is questionable for a variety of reasons; it is not my intent to endorse the practice, rather I'm just explaining one necessary element.

Comment: Additional reading: [Does Windows have a limit of 2000 threads per process?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050729-14/?p=34773). Plus, if you're creating thousands of threads, you are doing it wrong. The OS will likely provide a far better solution to the actual problem you are trying to solve (e.g. thread pools, I/O completion ports, etc.).